# Return inner join in EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to learn ASP.NET MVC, so I did as test project this where I want to display in Index a list of cities and when you click on city to see the properties in those cities.
[image: my edmx]

Then I did some changes in global.asax in order to come up with nice URLs:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
          "Home-Browse",
          "Accommodation-{city}",
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Browse", city = "" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

So now after I see the list of cities and I click one I get a URL like: `/Accommodation-Amsterdam`
My problem is that I don't know how to do the inner join in order to tell the controller to show me the properties in the area selected. (I told you I'm just learning this)

My home controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using accomm2.Models;

namespace accomm2.Controllers
{
    [HandleError]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        dataEntities _db;

        public HomeController()
        {
            _db = new dataEntities();
        }


        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData.Model = _db.Cities.ToList();

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Browse()
        {
          //ViewData.Model = _db.Properties.ToList();


            var properties = from c in _db.Cities
                             from p in c.Properties
                             where c.CityId == CityId
                        select c;


            return View(properties.ToList()); 

        }
    }
}
```

Could somebody help me with my Linq query or at least direct me to the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your Browse controller, just add `string city` as an argument, and it will magically be populated by MVC.

Comment: Thank you added but still where c.CityId == CityId is in red and tells me name CityId doesn't exist in current context ...

Comment: tried to add  where c.CityName == City and no red border but when i run i get :The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[accomm2.Models.City]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[accomm2.Models.Property]'.

Comment: You will also need to join on your City table to get to the name.  In this case, you won't need the city id.

Comment: Thank you i know is better to get them via CityId instead of name but as i don't have any experience with Linq query i didn't know how to do the query .. could you help me please?

Comment: i thought i joined the city table here :from c in _db.Cities                          from p in c.Properties                          where c.CityId == CityId                     select c;

Comment: Actually, give this a shot: 
from p in _db.Properties
where p.City.Name == city
select p

Comment: This worked great modified like this:from p in _db.Properties
                             where p.City.CityName == City
                             select p; I will vote your answer but still i think was better to get him via CityId instead of name , thank you verry much

Comment: If you would prefer to get the City id, you can make your URL look like this:  Accommodation-Amsterdam-12345 or like this: 12345/Accommodation-Amsterdam.  That way, the search engines still see the city name.